# Google spreadsheet will not print or download

Tags: pdf, google-sheets, printing, download

I have tried Google help and support and they could not solve the issue I am having.
One particular spreadsheetat:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11JxbhDbTiXP106rx7p9uB0qHImZG5TeIH0JReGUeWRo/edit#gid=40
will not print.

They suggested posting here.
I don't have the problem with other spreadsheets - only this one.
Neither will the spreadsheet download to my desktop and I cannot download a PDF file from it either - yet I can from my other spreadsheets and Google Docs.
Since other spreadsheets print, I assume the issue is within Google Sheets. I have tried different browsers and different machines - a Chromebook and my phone and the problem persists...

I have also tried duplicating the Spreadsheet but this displays the same issues; no printing. Trying to print just displays 'sent to Printer and never completes. Have to use Windows 'Task Manager' to close the window.
I do have some scripts in the document for sending PDF files to an email address - but this comes up with an error: 'Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with ID #' but the sheet should be able to print. I haven't edited the
sheets for maybe two years or more except to remove some unused rows today after reading reports of Large sheets displaying the error when running a script...
I should add when I contacted Google Help, we went through all of the usual suspects - clearing cache, trying incognito mode etc - all to no avail.
Can anyone advise, please?

Comment: I don't know all-thing Google docs, but is it because it is set as `View Only` a factor? I found [this info](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494893?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cdont-let-people-download-print-or-copy-your-file) seems related to the limits of what is described.

Comment: Although I had tried to open your sample Spreadsheet to test your current issue, unfortunately, I couldn't open your sample Spreadsheet. I apologize for this. Can you confirm it?

Comment: Not sure why you could not open it... it is set so that anyone with the link should be able to view.. but try this link:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11JxbhDbTiXP106rx7p9uB0qHImZG5TeIH0JReGUeWRo/edit?usp=sharing Even with 'View' only settings, I believe you should be able to print a sheet or download as a PDF.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, it seems that your sample Spreadsheet cannot be exported. So I couldn't test your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.